# Dynamically fetch feeds and html content from other website and show

Tags: 7

Is there any module that pulls data from external feed or html link and displays in drupal. It should not create any corresponding nodes in drupal. It should just go and scrape data or feed and display in a page or block.

Answer (score 1):

[Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) is the way to go. It includes an HTML parser and can fetch data from existing URLs.

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/856644) are some links to parsers for Feeds that can suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Aggregator Module which comes with Drupal. This allows you to fetch feeds and display them as blocks or use them in views and so on.

Comment: How about html data ?

Answer (score -1):

Not Aggregator Module alone, you need [Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/aggregation) also. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... aggregates content from XML feeds. RSS 2.0, ATOM 1.0 & RDF 1.0 are supported, but its architecture is easily expandable to support any XML format, check out the README file for details. Following are some of its features :
>
> - Highly efficient. This module was created for performance.
> - Ability to assign term(s) to all items generated from a feed.
> - Ability to dynamically tag all incoming items during feed handling phase. For example, RSS, ATOM & RDF categories are automatically extracted, added as terms, and auto-attached to aggregated items.
> - Integrates with OG. If the feed is set as a group, all items are assigned as posts under it (parent->child). If the feed is set as a post, all items are assigned as posts under the feed's group (siblings).
> - Built-in support for handling feeds that require HTTP authentication.
> - Built-in support for handling feeds that require FTP authentication.

Comment: How about html data ?

Comment: I think you need to manage it yourself with cUrl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Basic curl example http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: Question is tagged for Drupal 7, but that module only has Drupal 5 and 6 versions.

Comment: Answer doesn't fit the question : no D7 version, no direct HTML data fetching.